Deploy em uma aplicação React Vite
Bom dia, senhores. Realizei um deploy de uma aplicação construída em React Vite, o deploy foi feito dentro de um cPanel. A aplicação rodou normalmente, assim como outras que tenho, porém, nessa em específico, utiliza um arquivo de som para rodar um metrônomo. No localhost, o arquivo roda normalmente, fiz o npm run build e fiz o deploy no cPanel, e no site com o domínio, o React não reconhece mais o arquivo de som, mesmo ele inserido junto dos arquivos, como posso fazer pra reverter essa situação? Vocês tem alguma dica para deploy para aplicações React no cPanel?
Desde já, agradeço imensamente =)
